# Find YAML by key and change the value

Tags: symfony, yaml

I want to parse the contents of any .yml file and modify any key.

Let's take the security.yml file, get its contents and use Yaml::parse, which will return an array of arrays with its structure.

```
$yml='/config/security.yml';    
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().$yml;
$contents= Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));
```

This outputs

```
array(1) {
  ["security"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["encoders"]=>
    string(8) "Array(1)"
    ["role_hierarchy"]=>
    string(8) "Array(3)"
    ["providers"]=>
    string(8) "Array(2)"
    ["firewalls"]=>
    string(8) "Array(2)"
    ["access_control"]=>
    string(9) "Array(14)"
  }
}
```

So far so good. Now let's say I want to change the value of `security.firewalls.main.pattern`. I need to change the array value `$contents['security']['firewalls']['main']['pattern']` and then file_put_contents the yaml dump.

My question is how to get and set a parameter value, dynamically, by any key and not hard-code it like above. The Yaml parser doesn't have any way to get a value by its key. I need a way to transform `security.firewalls.main.pattern` into array keys, somehow. I will delete the cache afterwards, obviously.

I made something in the meanwhile:

```
   $array = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));  
   $keys=array("security","firewalls","main");
   $val = $this->parseYmlArray($array, $keys);

   public function parseYmlArray($array, $keys)
    {
        $newArr = $array;
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $newArr = $newArr[$key];
        }
        return $newArr;
    }
```

This will return whatever node, but it needs an array in the exact order of the keys depth.

I was thinking initially if I could make a ParameterBag just like the one in the Container. The problem is that I can't seem to find where it is created from an associative array in depth to one like key->value(security.firewalls.main.pattern and its value, for instance). If I try to create a ParameterBag out of an array, it doesn't modify that array, the bag contains the exact same array. I'm trying to find where the array is being parsed and transformed into the one in the container.

Comment: Maybe take a look at property accessors: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html

Comment: Might be worth looking into, maybe I can refactor my above function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't see any alternative to update your configuration values directly.

But, you can achieve this by defining parameters.

For example, you can change your `security.firewalls.main.pattern` like follows:

```
parameters:
    firewall_main_pattern: ^/yourpattern
    # ...

firewalls:
    # ...
    main:
        pattern: %firewall_main_pattern%
        # ...
```

Then, update the parameter as needed:

```
$this->container->setParameter('firewall_main_pattern', '^/yournewpattern');
```

Hope this solves to your problem.

**Update**

In the same kind of your `parseYmlArray`, you can use the following to change a value :

```
function assignConfigurationValueByPath(&$array, $path, $value) {
    $keys = explode('.', $path);
    while ($key = array_shift($keys)) {
        $arr = &$arr[$key];
    }

    $arr = $value;
}

$array = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));
assignConfigurationValueByPath($array, 'security.firewalls.main.pattern, 'new_value');
```

Now `$array` is changed to:

```
array(
    'security' => array(
        // ...
        'firewalls' => array(
             // ...
             'main' => array(
                 // ...
                 'pattern' => 'new_value'
             ),
        ),
    ),
):
```

Comment: It does not. I am looking for a way to dynamically and not manually change them. I am rebuilding the cache after I've modified them.

Comment: How I understood your question, you are currently parsing the YAML, change the values manually and rewrite the whole configuration file, and you are looking for a way to change the parameter without hard-coding an yaml parsing. This is why I propose you to do it in a cleaner way.  Maybe precise your question by talking about avoiding cache rebuild and make the changes dynamically rather than define it manually.

Comment: Using setParameter is not going to help.  The services which actually use firewall_main_pattern are actually compiled into a cached container definition file.  There is no practical way to modify them outside of a compiler pass.  Take a look at the cache directory.  Lots of fun stuff going on.

Comment: Well, modifying the firewall was an example. The purpose was to modify any .yml, not this one in particular. Compiler passes don't allow for dynamic modification. They need to come from .yml files.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now, thank's.
@GeorgeIrimiciuc If you update a configuration value (coming from any config file) without [recompiling the container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-separate-compiler-passes), you can't get the up-to-date configuration in the same request.

Comment: Yes, the cache needs to be cleared afterwards. But in my case it is fine. The alternative was to have a compiler pass get the data from a file, but why add another file in the project when it's already inside an yml?

Comment: After a lot of unsuccessful tries, I can't find a dynamic way to set the config value. Sorry ! I hope someone can answer you.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc I've added changes

Comment: I've made something similar myself, but this looks cleaner. I think I'll use it.

Comment: Just that assignConfigurationValueByPath can't use 'security.firewalls.main.pattern' as 2nd parameter, it needs to be an array of each of those values.